# How to add transition effects to jQuery image slider?

Tags: javascript, css, slider, gallery, transition

I have made a simple image slider based on this tutorial [here](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-foundations/making-simple-image-slider-html-css-jquery/). Looks like this:

```js
var currentIndex = 0,
          items = $('.container div'),
          itemAmt = items.length;

        function cycleItems() {
          var item = $('.container div').eq(currentIndex);
          items.hide();
          item.css('display', 'inline-block');
        }

        var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {
          currentIndex += 0;
          if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
            currentIndex = 0;
          }
          cycleItems();
        }, 3000);

        $('.next').click(function() {
          clearInterval(autoSlide);
          currentIndex += 1;
          if (currentIndex > itemAmt - 1) {
            currentIndex = 0;
          }
          cycleItems();
          slide();
        });

        $('.prev').click(function() {
          clearInterval(autoSlide);
          currentIndex -= 1;
          if (currentIndex < 0) {
            currentIndex = itemAmt - 1;
          }
          cycleItems();
          slide();
        });
```

```css
.container {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
.container div {
  display: inline-block;
  display: none;
}
.container img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: cover;
}
.galer-btn {
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
  top: 50%;
}
.next {
  right: 40px;
  padding: 20% 2% 20% 40%;
  margin: -20% -1%;
}
.prev {
  left: 40px;
  padding: 20% 40% 20% 2%;
  margin: -20% -2%;
}
.fa {
  font-size: 4vw;
  color: #ffd2cf;
}
.fa:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-animation: bounceright .3s alternate ease infinite;
  animation: bounceright .3s alternate ease infinite;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css">
</head>
<body>
  <section class="about">
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-right galer-btn next"></i>
    <i class="fa fa-chevron-left galer-btn prev"></i>
    <div class="container">
      <div style="display: inline-block;">
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/tech" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/tech" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/tech" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <img src="https://placeimg.com/1000/600/tech" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </section>
</body>

</html>
```

The result gives me full-screen image slider, which in tutorial is intended to auto slide, but I have managed to disable that by changing `currentIndex += 1;` to `currentIndex += 0;` in javascript code. Btw, any recommendations on how to remove the auto slide properly are welcomed.

However, the main question is how do I add some transition effects between images like fade-out etc.?

Also, for left and right buttons I have simply used FontAwesome icons, and it kinda works, but something tells me that might not be the best approach.. Should I use `<button>` or smthn instead?

So far I have only been learning HTML and CSS, and javascript (or jQuery) is a complete mystery to me right now, so I appreciate any help.

Comment: So currently your slider does not work at all. What was your issue again? Also, what/which CSS *transitions* are you referring to? (P.S: regarding the icons, you can use whatever *element* you want; usually some anchor or custom-styled *button*, but you can use really anything)

Comment: If you changed `currentIndex` to `0` you did it wrong. The `currentIndex` is used in that code to keep track of the current slide. You should instead remove `var autoSlide = setInterval(function() {` entirely, aswell as the `clearTimeout`s - if you don't want it to auto-slide.  (That's also one pretty bad example of how to build a "simple" jQuery slideshow...)